# OS X default input language

Tags: macos, language

I have three languages in macOS Sierra. I want to set a default one, when I open new window in browser, for example, English.

Usually it's so but sometimes it's another one that I use rarely. And I can't understand when it's English and when another one. 
I'm new to Mac, in Windows there is default language option. Is there some option like this in macOS?

[image]

Comment: Your system language is set to English. You should never see a non-English GUI provided you have installed properly localized apps only and didn't choose another GUI language in an app explicitly. Opening a site in a browser, you can be redirected to another "language specific" sub-site depending on your geo-location/region settings though (e.g. Google or a lot of well known corporate sites like Apple).

Comment: Probably I did not describe my question very good. The problem is that sometimes when I open new tab in browser, returning from skype input keyboard language is set to ukrainian. But I want to have it English always for something new

Comment: Please check: [How to set the input mode for each application in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/718463/how-to-set-the-input-mode-for-each-application-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

You keyboard input language is controlled by system preferences/keyboard/input sources and what you select in the "flag" menu in the Menu Bar (not by Language and Region).  Check your settings there.

Answer (score -1):

Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Language & Region.

Do one of the following:

Add a language: Click the Add button , select one or more languages in the list, then click Add.

The list is divided by a separator line. Languages above the line are system languages that are fully supported by OS X and are shown in menus, messages, websites, and more. Languages below the line aren’t fully supported by OS X, but may be supported by apps that you use, and shown in their menus and messages, and on some websites.

Delete all the languages that you do not use and it will be done :D

Comment: But those preferences have nothing to do with the input language, which is in the Keyboard preferences.